# Get object reference name in Java for constructing XML

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I am writing custom XML marshaller using XML generators. I am stuck with tag names writing.

Example:

```
     List<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
      userList.add("UserA");
      userList.add("UserB");
     Map<String, Object> systemMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     systemMap.put("SystemA",userList);
```

My requirement is:

```
      <SystemA>
          <userList> 
             [userA,userB]
          </userList>
      </SystemA>
```

Comment: So you need to write your own marshaller? Can't you use XStream?

Comment: If you are writing a custom marshaller why don't you use the annotations,. That way you are not bound to using a map of names and values .. Or just use jaxB

Comment: @edubriguenti all i have is Object no pojo will be available. and this object may be of 2 type either list or map. and this list or map again may contain list or map and hierarchy goes on.

Comment: Classic XY problem. You are never going to 'get the object reference name'. What you are really asking is how to get the desired output, not how to get it from the code sample you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using Jaxb. Please extract inner classes to file before implementing.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class ParsingTest {

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Marshaller marshaller;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SystemA.class);
        marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testParse() throws Exception {
        final SystemA systemA = new SystemA();
        final List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add("userA");
        users.add("userB");
        systemA.setUserList(users);

        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(systemA, stringWriter);
        System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
        Assert.assertTrue(true);

        // XMLUnit.compareXML(stringWriter.toString(), reader);

    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "SystemA")
    @XmlType(name = "SystemA", propOrder = {
            "userList"
    })
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class SystemA {

        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomAdapter.class)
        private Collection<String> userList;

        public Collection<String> getUserList() {
            return userList;
        }

        public void setUserList(Collection<String> userList) {
            this.userList = userList;
        }
    }

    public static class CustomAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Collection<String>> {

        @Override
        public Collection<String> unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
            return new ArrayList<>();// TODO String -> List;
        }

        @Override
        public String marshal(Collection<String> v) throws Exception {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("[");
            for (String s : v) {
                stringBuilder.append(s);
                stringBuilder.append(",");
            }

            stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.lastIndexOf(","));
            stringBuilder.append("]");
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SystemA>
    <userList>[userA,userB]</userList>
</SystemA>
```